# Activerecord: Converting strings to times in the local time

Tags: activerecord, timezone

I've read quite a few articles, done my homework. I have all times stored as UTC, each user sets their own time zone, etc. Here's the problem I'm having:

```
Time.zone
=> GMT-05:00 Eastern Time US  Canada

t = Ticket.first
t.hold_until = "Jan 1, 2012 9:00PM"
t.save!

t.hold_until
=> Sun, 01 Jan 2012 16:00:00 EST -05:00

# notice the above time lost 5 hours
```

The issue is that the string is from a POST request supplied by the user. Doesn't it make the most sense to assume user input is in their local time, not UTC. Am I missing something or shouldn't that be the ActiveRecord default? Whats the proper way to do this, beyond having to convert the time in all of my controllers. That just seems wrong and not very DRY.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue and it has to do with poorly written code within ActiveRecord (surprise!). Anyways, ActiveRecord::Base.define_attribute_methods gets called lazily via method missing. I had this method defined like so:

```
def hold_until=(value)
  # do some stuff here
  super
end
```

So ActiveRecord was skipping that method thinking it was defined. It shouldn't matter, but due to poor design it does. AR has a variety of different ways to define methods based on their column type. Calling super side steps this and goes right to a general "write_attribute" call. The only solution is to convert the time yourself. You can't call define_attribute_methods before you include the modules because of all the alias_method_chain bullshit. And you can't leverage the code they've already written because its in a class_eval block. I would recommend datamapper if at all possible.